# Why do tools estimate my AdSense earnings to be much greater than actuallity?

Tags: google-adsense, monetize

I use Google AdSense at a site with about 15000 page views monthly. If I use some tools the check my website's values then it says that it has a certain value and that I should be able to earn much more than I'm actually doing (I use solely google AdSense).

What could be the reason for my low AdSense earnings compared to the estimates of the tools, when the tools estimate a much higher profit from advertising than I actually make?

My web health score in AdSense is 5/5 and my income optimization in AdSense is 4/5, but is it AdSense itself that is suboptimal and I've missed some good source that the tools assume I could or should use, or is my SEO that is sub-par, or is it simply the tools that are not making a decent valuation?

I certainly would like to do as well as the tools say, but the tools report something similar to me record and peak in AdSense for a single day and not close to my average. For instance, one tools says that with my URL as input, the tool reports that the site `could`make 100 USD daily and that estimate is much more than daily AdSense average. So maybe I'm missing something or the tools are just overvaluing the website?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These so called tools that valuate your site, are junk sites to get traffic and ad impressions. Nothing more.

It is impossible for an outsider to know how much traffic your site has, how many ad impressions you have made, and your click-through rate. Often they use free metrics such as Alexa which is pure garbage. These are junk calculations, but amazingly, the most accurate are about double the reality which is predicable.

Do not waste your time using these sites. Just focus on SEO and building traffic. The Google tools have huge holes in them though there is still a treasure trove of value to be had. Install a good web analytics tool such as http://piwik.org/ and use a good SEO tool such as SEO PowerSuite http://www.seopowersuite.com/.

Answer (score 1):

$100 on a 15,000 page views is a $6.66 CPM.   It is not unreasonable to get a $6 CPM using AdSense.

If your CPM is actually in the $2 to $3 range, it sounds to me like you could optimize the layout of your ads to entice users to notice them.

- Use one or two ads above the fold
- Place ads between content rather than around the edges of the page
- Use only the following ad sizes which have the most inventory:

  - 336x280 large rectangle
  - 300x250 medium rectangle
  - 728x90 leaderboard
  - 160x600 wide skyscraper
- Match the colors of your ad to your page

  - Background of the ad matches the background of the page
  - Border color of the ad matches the background of the page (no border)
  - Text color of the ad matches the text color of the page
  - Link color of the ad matches the link color of the page
- Ensure that your first ad (in your page source code) is your biggest and most prominent one.  Remove small ads from your header and left sidebar if they come before a more prominent ad in the content section.

Comment: FYI, it is against the AdSense terms of service to share your CPC and RPM stats.